# How to scale/rotate an image in high quality with Allegro 5?

Tags: interpolation, allegro5

The API seems to provide only [al_draw_scaled_bitmap](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/graphics.html#al_draw_scaled_bitmap) or [al_draw_rotated_bitmap](http://liballeg.org/a5docs/trunk/graphics.html#al_draw_rotated_bitmap) and few others very similar.
These functions are very fast, the only problem is the quality. If I scale or rotate the same image with any image editor the quality is much better. With Allegro I clearly see jagged edges and pixels.

With GIMP, for example, for scaling an image, there are three options: "Linear", "Cubic" and "Sinc (Lanczos 3)". Aren't these algorithms hardware accelerated? Are there in Allegro?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable linear interpolation with Allegro like this:

`al_set_new_bitmap_flags(ALLEGRO_MIN_LINEAR | ALLEGRO_MAG_LINEAR);`

Before loading your bitmaps.